# MVC - Getting membership provider to work

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have MVC 1.0 app developing with VS2008. Brave!

I have developer edition of SQL 2005 installed.

I ran the aspnet_regsql.exe to add membership schema to my DB.

When i try to register a user I get this error:

The user instance login flag is not supported on this version of SQL Server. The connection will be closed.

I have modified the machine.config to point to my server and db.
Also added LocalSqlServer connection string to web.config same error.

Any ideas why this error is occurring??

Malcolm

Comment: I found out why. It is not using LocalSqlServer connectionstring.

Answer (score 1):

This a misconfiguration.  It looks like the connection string being used is trying to create or use a database that doesn't exist.  Make sure your connection string is pointing to the right database.  By default the application services (Membership, Profile, Roles) use the ApplicationServices connection string in your project's web.config file.